# How to shut down my pc like it does when it is running out of battery?

Tags: battery, hibernate, low-power

How do I put my pc (ubuntu 16.04) in the same state as when in automatically tuns off when the battery level is too low (without letting it die of course).

It is interesting for me because open apps aren't closed when this happens, so I can still save my work. I can't hibernate because it freezes the computer (I already tried everything so that isn't the issue here).

Thank you for your respond if you can think of something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean but if 'hibernate' means the same as 'suspend' then everything that was on screen should still be there when you wake it up again. But maybe some apps are crashed by this process. The only alternative I'm aware of is going to 'Brightness & lock' in 'System Settings' and telling the screen to 'Turn of when inactive for: 1 minute. This will blank your screen soon but leave everything running.

Maybe you've tried all that but I'm running 16.04 and I'm not aware of any other kind of hibernating mode. I was assuming that a laptop goes into 'suspend' mode when the battery is dying but maybe I'm wrong about that.

Answer (score 0):

`systemctl suspend` (check [systemd-service.suspend](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/systemd-suspend.service.8.html) man page)